# NGINX rewrite one URL with parameter to another URL with new parameters

Tags: php, nginx, parameters, url-rewriting, typo3

I want to redirect one specific URL with parameters as 301 to another specific URL with a new parameter.

https://www.example.com/index.php?id=329

to

https://www.example.com/index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap

I tried something but I think there are several mistakes.

```
location = /index.php?id=329 {
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com/index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap permanent;
}
```

OR

```
location = /index.php {
    if ($arg_id = "329") {
        rewrite ^ https://www.example.com/index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap permanent;
    }
}
```

OR

```
location = /index.php {
    if ($args ~ "id=329") {
        rewrite ^ https://www.example.com/index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap permanent;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `/index.php` URI is processed by the `location ~ \.php$` block, and includes all of the necessary statements to send the filename to PHP for execution. If you are going to create a new `location` for `/index.php`, you will need to duplicate these statements also.

For example:

```
location = /index.php {
    if ($arg_id = "329") {
        return 301 /index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap;
    }
    ... php statements ...
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ... php statements ...
}
```

Alternatively, check the URI **before** it enters a `location` block.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    if ($request_uri = "/index.php?id=329") {
        return 301 /index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap;
    }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for more.